# sql server 2008 - import data into existing tables from XML files

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, import

Before data is removed from an sql server database, it is exported and saved as an XML file in the event that this data is to be recovered at a later stage.  I am now trying to get the data back into the database from an XML file but cannot find the best way to do this.  The SQL server import / export wizard does not appear to support XML.  I have looked at the XML Bulk Load component but this doesn't look like it would work for my issue. Has anyone any suggestions?

The XML may look like below and I woud want each row inserting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
<product>
<prod_id>4235823</prod_id>
<productImageURL>image1.jpg</productImageURL>
<entryDate>Aug 30 2011 01:47:08:317PM</entryDate>
<category>859191</category>
<productDescription>product description 1</productDescription>
<productName>product name 1</productName>
<Price>9.99</Price>
</product>
<product>
<prod_id>8989595</prod_id>
<productImageURL>image2.jpg</productImageURL>
<entryDate>Aug 30 2011 01:47:08:317PM</entryDate>
<category>859191</category>
<productDescription>product description 2</productDescription>
<productName>product name 2</productName>
<Price>2.99</Price>
</product>
<product>
<prod_id>4575454</prod_id>
<productImageURL>image3.jpg</productImageURL>
<entryDate>Aug 30 2011 01:47:08:317PM</entryDate>
<category>859191</category>
<productDescription>product description 3</productDescription>
<productName>product name 3</productName>
<Price>5.99</Price>
</product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    p.value('prod_id[1]','INT'),
    p.value('productImageURL[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),
    p.value('category[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),
    p.value('productDescription[1]','VARCHAR(1000)'),
    p.value('productName[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),
    p.value('Price[1]','money'),            
FROM @xmlfile.nodes('/Products/Product') as Product(p)
```

Comment: great that looks straight forward, how does it get the XML file though? Also what does the number 1 in square brackets represent?

Comment: also it looks like its reading from the XML but how do you then insert the data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I found I needed the following:

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = N'<Products>
<Product>
<id>4</id>
<name>Amy</name>
<age>25</age>
</Product>
<Product>
<id>7</id>
<name>Vicky</name>
<age>40</age>
</Product>
</Products>'


INSERT INTO dbo.leanne_test (id, name, age)


SELECT
 doc.col.value('id[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') id
,doc.col.value('name[1]', 'varchar(100)') name 
,doc.col.value('age[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') age 
FROM @xml.nodes('/Products/Product') doc(col)
```